# How to make n-of turtles move to the same place every loop?

Tags: netlogo

I want to specify the number of turtles to go and back the same place every of my loop.
For example, in day1, some of turtles born in place1 and some of turtles born in place 2 and turtles its selves know the place where they want to go and come back to the same place where they born. For day2, turtles its selves still go the same place and go on  like this every day.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to work out what you are asking but hopefully this is close and will give us a starting point to work out what you actually want. This model has a variable for each turtle to remember where it was born, and each `tick` some (5) of the turtles move back to their home patch. The other turtles move in a random direction.

```
turtles-own [myhome]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set myhome patch-here
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let homers n-of 5 turtles
  ask turtles
  [ ifelse member? self homers
    [ move-to myhome ]
    [ set heading random 360
      forward 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```